# Ubuntu 18.04 freezing after login, only mouse movement working

Tags: login, mouse

The problem is that when I log in, the desktop appears, everything appears normally, but I can't click on anything.
While I am at the login screen, I can click and write my password, but after that I can't do anything else except moving the mouse.
Ubuntu 18.04.

Found an post in that anyone said it might be problem with xorg and this as solution:

```
apt install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Tried it, didn't help. I'm not sure if it even installed anything.

If it's important, last time that it worked was yesterday while I was trying to install some extensions.

[image: blkid]

[image: cat /etc/fstab]

[image: dpkg -l *nvidia*]

Comment: You have a problem with a GNOME extension. Do you know how to physically move/remove extensions when you can't work in your own login? It involves booting to recovery mode. Or... do you have any other admin accounts on this system?

Comment: I got Kali linux on the same machine, runned it and removed everything that i put in the extensions folder. Tried to boot ubuntu, and the problem still exist

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Also, what video card and driver do you have installed? Lastly, on the login screen, after selecting your username, click on the cog wheel icon, and tell me which environment is selected... it should probably be "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu on Xorg".

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nk033b
Sorry for the image, hope it helps. Doesn't know how to get screenshots in that situation.

Video card: MSI GeForce GTX 1050Ti.
Driver: i think i never tried to install/modify the drivers from the system installation.

The environment is ubuntu.
There is also ubuntu on wayland as option.

Comment: There's only one extension there, and it's pretty harmless. However, in your screenshot, I see another major problem. Edit your question and show me `sudo blkid` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Tell me what version Nvidia driver you have installed `dpkg -l *nvidia*`. Use imgur.com for screenshots, if you like.

Comment: Done. Again, sorry for the quality.

Comment: I made a minor edit to the sdb1 UUID in my answer.

Comment: status update please

Comment: Didn't work. i reinstalled the whole system and rebuild everything i had done form 0. 
But thanks anyways !

Comment: Did my procedure break down somewhere, or did it go ok, but the problem persisted?

Comment: Everything from your procedure gone fine, it fixed the problem with the swap but the major problem didn't been solved.

Comment: Did the reinstall finally fix the problem for you?

Comment: Of course, fresh install,  everything from the old system is removed.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a problem with your swap partition.

Screenshots or images make it a little difficult to give a 100% complete answer, but I'll give you the basics and that should be enough.

The `/etc/fstab` has a line where it tried to mount swap. It fails because the UUID that ends in c932 is incorrect. We have to edit `/etc/fstab` and replace that incorrect UUID, with the UUID that we see in the `sudo blkid` command... using the `/dev/sdb1` UUID that ends in 18cf.

Boot to recovery mode and enter this command(s):

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # assure the disk is r/w

`sudo blkid | grep sdb1` # show us the correct UUID

copy this UUID to the clipboard

`sudo pico /etc/fstab` # edit fstab

replace the bad UUID on the swap line, with edit/paste

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd> to save the edit

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit the editor

`reboot` # reboot the computer