# Ubuntu 20.04 Freezing right after logging in. Only mouse movement is possible

Tags: 20.04, freeze

#### symptom

My Ubuntu 20.04 gets freezing right after I log in (after a few seconds). I can only move my mouse cursor;I cannot select and click anything with my mouse and the keyboard doesn't work too. If I log in with another user (i.e. administrator) I don't have that problem.

It seems that there are some same issues (e.g. [Ubuntu 18.04 freezing after login, only mouse movement working](https://askubuntu.com/q/1139997/1180225)) but answers there don't work for me. Also, I am not using Nvidia; I am using an internal one of intel.

#### history

This problem happened when I was using the Libre office. Whenever I save a document or change the keyboard language (i.e. English to German), it froze. I forcefully rebooted the machine with the power button about 5 times whenever my machine froze.
After that, I got the Busybox problem (i.e. boot not to the normal Ubuntu, but to a kind of command line). I solved this problem by resetting the boot option according to this site (https://askubuntu.com/a/1157394). But, it still keeps freezing.

Answer (score 0):

I asked an IT center. Among their suggestions, I did the item #1 of the first bullet below and it worked.

- using the administrator account, to try renaming some of the other account's startup files to start with an initial configuration.

1. Start with .bash_profile, .bashrc, .inputrc, and .profile
2. If this is not helping continue with the directories .cache, .config, .dbus, and .local
3. If that doesn't help, create a temporary directory in the home folder and move everything from the home directory to that directory to start with a basic environment.
4. If either solution works, copy or rename the files or directories back to find the problem.

- If you are still having problems, hardware in the laptop may also be defective. In that case, the machine needs to be investigated further.